# Enable 'Show paint rectangles' without having Developer Tools open in Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, rendering, development

Google Chrome offers an option to visually highlight repainted areas using a Developer Tools option called 'Show paint rectangles'. It is described here: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/rendering-settings

Another of those options is FPS meter rendering. This option you can even enabled permanently by modifying chrome:flags, but I can't figure out how to permanently enable paint rectangles to be rendered for every page without the Developer Tools console open. There doesn't seem to be a flag for it I could enable.

Is there a solution to this? Maybe a setting or an extension to do it?

Comment: not posting as an answer since I couldn't get this to work, but Chromium has a `--show-paint-rects` switch which does this. I got this to work in my Electron app, but not by running `chrome.exe --show-paint-rects`

Answer (score 0):

While it is not a perfect solution, you can have the developer tools open in a separate window (undocked) in order to not obstruct the view. Downside is that you need to have developer tools open.

See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23668827/how-to-open-the-chrome-developer-tools-in-a-new-window

Comment: You should summarize the linked question and its accepted answer. Link-only answers aren't very useful by themselves and can become invalid if the linked page is taken offline.

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question